# UIButton target action not executed when using a different object

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I am using the generating a button within my code and using the addTarget() method to print "Hi" when the button is pressed. The code is below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let smartCarRequest = SmartCarOAuthRequest(clientID: "", redirectURI: "smartcar://oidc.com", scope: ["read_vehicle_info", "read_odometer"], development: true)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.smartCarSDK = SmartCarOAuthSDK()
    let sdk = appDelegate.smartCarSDK
    var ui = SmartCarOAuthSDK()

    print(sdk!)
    print(ui)

    ui.generateButton(for: OEM(oemName: OEMName.mock), in: self.view.subviews[0])
}
```

Currently, both the sdk and ui variables are a SmartCarOAuthSDK object. But generating the button and action with the sdk variable successfully executes the action, while using the ui variable does not print "Hi". The code for the button generation is below.

```
class SmartCarOAuthSDK {

    init() {
    }

    func generateButton(for oem: OEM, in view: UIView) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        button.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: oem.oemConfig.color)
        button.setTitle("LOGIN WITH " + oem.oemName.rawValue.uppercased(), for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)
        return button
    }  

    @objc func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Hi")
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an answer to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `ui` variable goes away as soon as `viewDidLoad` finishes.

To avoid this, you need to declare the variable as a class-level variable.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "ui" is a local object belong to method "viewDidLoad()". It will be destroyed after the end of viewDidLoad. That's why the ui variable is not working anymore.